# javascript regex test() not recognising danish characters

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

I have made a search-function, much like facebooks searchfield with autocomplete, using javascript and regex.
This works fine, however when i search for the danish letters Æ, Ø, Å, the .test() function won't recognize it properly and nothing is returned.

This is basically how the search part is working:

```
var regXSearch = "\\b"+sTerm;
//sTerm is the value of my search field       
var regX = new RegExp(regXSearch,"gi");
var nameCheck = regX.test(users[i]["User"]["name"]);
```

Imagine the usernames asbjørn, østergård and jason:

- if i search for "asbjør", "asb" or even "ørn" that will return true.
- if i search for "øster" or "østergård" it will return false.
- if i search "stergård", "ård" or even "rd" it will return true
- if i search for "j", "jas", "jaso" etc it will return true
- if i search for "ason" or "son" it will return false

i found a fiddle that is actually able to search with æøå, but it only works when you search for the entire word. i'm not good enough to decode how that works, but maybe you can use it to find a possible fix for my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/8Y3cM/17/

Is this fixable or do i need to switch to some kind of plugin search-function?

Comment: You haven't explained your question very well and that's probably why you've not got anyone else giving you an answer. With the issue you're having, format it as _code_ then _example data_ with _expected result_ and _actual result_ (one example at a time). I tried out `regXSearch = "\\b"+"ørn";` with `regX.test("asbjørn")` and got `true` as expected? Are you sure that you've saved everything in _UTF-8_ and that the page is being rendered using that charset, too?

Comment: Maybe i could have phrased my question a little better. My main problem is that javascript regex and the test() function doesnt support unicode.
My question was if anybody could help me out with a solution or a workaround.
With that said, the regex should only match from the beginning of the word. Therefor returning true if you search "ørn" is a mistake.

Comment: Word characters are considered to be `[a-zA-Z0-9]`, maybe you'd be better off matching `"(^|\s|-)" + sTerm`

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is twofold.

**First**: **`\b`** matches a *word break* on its position. A word break matches when on one of its sides you have a Word Character and on the other side a Not A Word Character. Your regex starts with `"\\b"+sTerm` and so it will fail for `jason` on `\bason` and `\bson`, but will match on `\bj`, `\bjas` and `\bjaso`. If there is 'nothing' on the left of a `\b` then it counts as 'not a word character' (there is no word character, see? :), and in the Fail cases there *is* something there, while in the Match cases there is not.

**Second**: the characters `ø` and `å` are *not* considered "word characters" in Javascript, as this simple test will show you:

```
alert ("østergård".match(/\W+/g));
```

Since they are not considered a word character, the behavior of `\b` is the reverse of what you *think* it does:

```
alert ("østergård".match(/\bøster/)); // null
```

It fails because `\b` sees a not-word character on its right (the `ø`) and so it should match a word character on its left (it doesn't, there is nothing there).

A small test suite for your sample cases:

```
var sTerm = [
    [ "asbjørn", "asbjør", "asb", "ørn" ],
    [ "østergård", "øster", "østergård" ],
    [ "østergård", "stergård", "ård", "rd" ],
    [ "jason", "j", "jas", "jaso" ],
    [ "jason", "ason", "son" ]
    ];

var r = '';
for (s=0; s<sTerm.length; s++)
{
    for (s2=1; s2<sTerm[s].length; s2++)
    {
        var regXSearch = "\\b"+sTerm[s][s2];
        //sTerm is the value of my search field       
        var regX = new RegExp(regXSearch,"gi");

        var nameCheck = regX.test(sTerm[s][0]);
        r += "["+sTerm[s][s2]+"] on ["+sTerm[s][0]+"] is "+nameCheck+'\r';
    }
}
alert (r);
```

shows the same order of `true` and `false` as you reported. If you remove the `\b` in `regXSearch` you will see that *all* return `true`.

#### Why does your own 'temporary fix' fix it?

You replace the non-word characters (nothing personal, this is just according to Javascript!) with valid word characters, and so you get the expected behavior of `\b` back.

A better fix is not to rely on this specific behavior of `\b` (and, by extension, `\w`). If these user names may appear anywhere in any text (so not just at the beginning of a string), you can use something like this:

```
var regXSearch = "(^|[^\\wøå])"+sTerm;
```

where the RegEx

```
(^|[^\\wøå])
```

stands for

- `^` beginning of string
- `|` OR
- `[^...]`  NOT (`^`) any of the characters `\w`, `ø`, `å`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make a temporary fix by having two different variables containing the same set of users - One containing the real names with æøå and another with replaced values. (for the search function to look at)

If somebody is having a similar issue, the function to replace characters looks like this:

```
var mapObj = { æ:"ae", ø:"oe", å:"aa", Æ:"AE", Ø:"OE", Å:"AA" };

               sTerm = sTerm.replace(/æ|ø|å|Æ|Ø|Å/gi, function(matched){
                    return mapObj[matched];
             });
```

if someone has a better solution, i'm still interested. :)